# SQL - Get multiple closest value

Tags: mysql, sql

i want make sql query that will search database to find multiple closest value
I have following query to find closest value.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE price >= (50 * .9) and price <= (50 * 1.1)
order by abs(price - 50) LIMIT 1;
```

Its working fine, but i want to make that it will search more than one values something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE price >= (50 * .9) and price <= (50 * 1.1) //here i want one result (limit 1)
or price >= (50 * 1.9) and price <= (50 * 2.1) //here i want one result (limit 1)
order by abs(price - 50)
```

I want for each price limit 1 not find all values.
How i can do this?

//edit
just found answer.

```
(select *
  from table
  WHERE price >= (50 * .9) and price <= (50 * 1.1)
  order by abs(price - 50)
  limit 1
) union all
(select *
  from table
  WHERE price >= (50 * 1.9) and price <= (50 * 2.1)
  order by abs(price - 50)
  limit 1
)
```

Comment: Because you are ordering in ascending order, the second query will always return the same as the first (if the first is not empty). this makes the first one useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `union all`?

```
(SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE price >= (50 * 0.9) and price <= (50 * 1.1)
 ORDER BY ABS(price - 50)
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE price >= (50 * 1.9) and price <= (50 * 2.1)
 ORDER BY ABS(price - 2*50)
 LIMIT 1
) ;
```

Comment: `ABS(price - 2*50)` ?

Comment: Yes, i just found it on another site. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

do you want this

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE price >= (50 * .9) and price <= (50 * 1.1) //here i want one result    (limit 1)
 union
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE price >= (50 * 1.9) and price <= (50 * 2.1) //here i want one result  (limit 1)
 order by abs(price - 50)
```